# What's the difference between hybrid and progressive web apps?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, progressive-web-apps

I want to know whats's difference between a hybrid mobile app and a progressive web app?

Maybe I know the answer. But I'm not sure and I can't find a clear solution. As far as I know, a native app is a normal smartphone app which was developed with Android/Java or Swift (iOS). I have access to the operating system which runs on the smartphone and hardware near stuff like the battery level.

With a hybrid app, which can be developed with Ionic 2/3 or React Native, I have a few functions and possibilities like the Push Notifications. But less functions and possibilities than in Android or Swift. Hybrid Apps are a mix between native and web apps. So they are developed with different javascript frameworks. Ionic 2 uses Angular 1.x and Ionic 3 now uses Angular 4. I'm not sure if an newer version of Ionic 2 uses Angular 2 or an older version of Ionic 3 uses Angular 2. It's possible that they skipped Angular 2. React Native uses of course React. I have access to the operating system, but as example I can't have access to the battery level.

A progressive web app is a web app which works on the smartphone. I can use pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript or different frameworks like Bootstrap,  Angular or React. But I don't have to use Ionic or React Native.

Am I right?

One big difference is that progressive web apps uses a service worker.

I don't know whats the right word. But if I create a new Android app I also can use HTML, CSS and JS inside the Android app. Are this called a progressive web app or does it have also word?

What else are differences between hybrid mobile apps and progressive web apps?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 3):

*Hybrid apps* are apps build with web technology (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) and run in a native app using a webview, ie hybrid. These apps are packaged and go through one of the appstores. By using plugins all native functionality can be used. The web frameworks used are not what's making it 'hybrid', it's the web application running inside the native app.

A *progressive web app* is an enhancement on a 'normal' website giving it superpowers. It is fast, reliable and engaging. It can run outside of the browser being placed on the user's homescreen and it can run offline. It gives the user the feeling it is running a native app, by using modern web techniques native features like push messages (Web Push API). You must use HTTPS to keep it secure.

There is another option that goes inbetween, the *Hosted Web App*. In this case you are basically creating an empty packaged app that shows your website. Giving you store presence and the benifits of having your website run on its own.

Comment: You said "being placed on the user's homescreen " how do I do that in windows 10. I would like to try a PWA, place it on the homescreen. Where do I install it from?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which browsers support it right now. I think they all are working on it. Chrome works (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/). I think firefox nightly too.